# How to sum two fields in Python Advanced Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I need to perform a quite simple task (or at least it was simple on ArcGIS):

I have two numeric fields called `c0g1` and `c0g2`, and want to add them into a new field named `TOTAL`.

Must use the Advanced calculator because I need to batch the process. I simply do not know what to type in the Formula field (value =). Tried many things but nothing works... [image]

Answer (score 5):

Your task can be done in the following way:

If you want to access an existing attribute, that’s possible using <attribute_name>. The feature geometry can be accessed using $geom.

I recommend you to check this article https://anitagraser.com/2013/04/20/advanced-python-field-calculator/

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much